# Annotation Type Expected

Tags: junit, intellij-idea

I just created this unit test, and I get a red squiggly under `@Test` that says "Annotation Type Expected". What does this mean?

```
package com.sample.bank.account;

import junit.framework.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class LoanTest {

    @Test
    public void testAppliyPaymentSubtractsCorrectAmount()
    {
        Loan loan = new Loan("test subtract", 1000);
        loan.applyPayment(100);
        assertEquals(900, loan.getBalance());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The import should be

```
import org.junit.Test;
```

and not

```
import junit.framework.Test;
```

Answer (score 5):

The import should be

```
import org.junit.Test;
```

If you are using jUnit 4.

If you are using upto jUnit 3.8.

```
import junit.framework.Test;
```

should work fine.